# Extract property with xslt

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml content in a file:

```
<testsuite errors="1" failures="1" name="unittest.suite.TestSuite" tests="3" time="6.540">
  <properties>
    <property name="comp1" value="0.0.0.0:80=0.0.1"/>
    <property name="comp2" value="12.34.56.78:80=0.0.1"/>
```

and I want to create a table like

```
Name  Value
comp1 0.0.0.0:80=0.0.1
comp2 12.34.56.78:80=0.0.1
```

with an xsl. I tried the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>    
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="testsuite/properties/property">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="value"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which just gives an empty table. How to do this correctly? I only found examples on the internet which were way to complex. If someone knows a good tutorial on such things, I am welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
```

When accessing an attribute you need `@` before the name.

Answer (score 3):

`@` is used for attributes, if you don't use then it will be by default treated as an element..

so your code works fine if the XML is like this:

```
<testsuite errors="1" failures="1" name="unittest.suite.TestSuite" tests="3" time="6.540">
  <properties>
    <property>
      <name>comp1</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:80=0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>comp2</name>
      <value>12.34.56.78:80=0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    ..........
    ........
```

And here is your corrected code, observe the usage of `@`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>    
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="testsuite/properties/property">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```